# "Error"...non-numeric argument to binary operator", yet all variables are numeric

Tags: r

I am fitting a Boosted Regression Model in R version 3.2.2, all my variables are numbers, but I can't proceed because of this error "Error in total.deviance/n.cases : non-numeric argument to binary operator". My data structure is as follows:

```
 str(uffe.data)
'data.frame':   1437 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ uffespeed  : num  0.162 0.298 0.317 0.261 0.759 ...
 $ uffepike   : num  0.419 0.419 0.419 0.419 0.419 ...
 $ uffeslope  : num  1.863 2.374 1.647 2.003 0.737 ...
 $ uffepop0999: num  15.6 15.6 15.6 15.6 15.6 ...
 $ uffedwater : num  359 2778 3112 2310 2726 ...
 $ uffedtown  : num  14139 11713 11330 12020 11654 ...
 $ ufferoads  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

my model is:

```
   uffebrt <- gbm.step(data=uffe.data, gbm.x = 2:7, 
     gbm.y = 1, family =      "gamma", tree.complexity = 5, 
     learning.rate = 0.01,bag.fraction = 0.5)
```

execution ends prematurely as follows:

```
Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL 

GBM STEP - version 2.9 


Performing cross-validation optimisation of a boosted regression tree model 
for uffespeed with dataframe uffe.data and using a family of gamma 

Using 1437 observations and 6 predictors 

Error in total.deviance/n.cases : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Even if I had access to your data I wouldn't be able to reproduce this - my `dismo::gbm.step` doesn't allow `family='gamma'` (using `dismo 1.0-12` and `gbm 2.1.1`). Can you also double-check that your code/data are consistent with what you're actually using ?- I see that your error message refers to `u.data` and `uffe.speed`, not to `uffe.data` and `uffespeed`.

Comment: Thanks, those were type edits, I typed in the last section. I have just corrected.

Comment: @jbaums: Thank you, after changing family to "gaussian", it worked, though am not sure its the best family for my data distribution. many thanks for the tip.

Comment: @jbaums, maybe worth posting as answer (at the very least it's not a very helpful error message ...)

Comment: I'm not sure where the first part of your output is coming from (with `Length Class Mode`) - maybe `nrow()` is being masked somehow, in which case `n.cases` might not be numeric after all. Hard to say, but you should report back to let us know whether you get the same output with a fresh R session and after reinstalling `dismo` and `gbm`.

Comment: @jbaums The code works well as long as I change the family from 'gamma' to 'gaussian'. Even after restarting R, reinstalling dismo and gbm; when I  re-insert 'gamma', the same error persists.

Answer (score 1):

The `gbm.step` function from the `dismo` package allows `family` to be one of: `'bernoulli'`, `'binomial'`, `'poisson'`, `'laplace'`, or `'gaussian'`. If you provide a family that's not one of those, `calc.deviance`, which is called by `gbm.step`, should throw the following error:

```
Error in calc.deviance(y_i, u_i, weights = site.weights, family = family,  : 
  unknown family, should be one of: "binomial", "bernoulli", "poisson", "laplace", "gaussian"
```

Your error message suggests that `calc.deviance` didn't throw that error as expected, since `total.deviance/n.cases`, which is referred to in your error message, appears (directly) after the call to `calc.deviance` in the source of `gbm.step`.

The error complains that one or the other of `total.deviance` or `n.cases` is non-numeric. From looking at the source we can safely assume it's not `n.cases`, . That leaves `total.deviance`, which is calculated as the result of the `calc.deviance` call. My guess is that for some reason, `calc.deviance` is assigning a character string to `total.deviance`.

I can't explain why this might be happening, but from your comments I suspect that using one of the accepted families will solve your problem. Do you get the error in a fresh R session? Perhaps if you reinstall `dismo` from CRAN it might behave as expected.

For future reference, the `debug` function is very useful for exploring problems like these, since it allows you to step through the source, examining the objects that are created at any point.

As a side note, the information printed to screen falsely suggests that the gamma family might be supported, since it shows:

```
## Performing cross-validation optimisation of a boosted regression tree model 
## for uffespeed with dataframe uffe.data and using a family of gamma
```

But consider the `family` provided in the following, and the ensuing message:

```
gbm.step(data=get(data(Anguilla_train))[1:200, ], 
         gbm.x=3:14, gbm.y=2, tree.complexity=5, learning.rate=0.01, 
         bag.fraction = 0.5, family="kittens")

## GBM STEP - version 2.9 

## Performing cross-validation optimisation of a boosted regression tree model 
## for Angaus and using a family of kittens 
## Using 200 observations and 12 predictors
```

The message is printed before error-checking is performed, which is a tad misleading. But at least in my case I also see:

```
Error in calc.deviance(y_i, u_i, weights = site.weights, family = family,  : 
  unknown family, should be one of: "binomial", "bernoulli", "poisson", "laplace", "gaussian"
```